# listing the selected record from database.

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, sqldatasource

in my database there are id,name,surname,city fields.

let's imagine there are 30 people who has same name. i want to do that;

after selecting name  from dropdownlist1, dropdownlist2 only shows city names base on selected name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `dropdownlist2` from Filter `DataSource`(that has only filter data) on [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event of `dropdownlist1`

Here I am giving some idea how to use first dropdown value as a parameter of second Data Source.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSource2" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Param = @param;"
    CancelSelectOnNullParameter="true">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dropDown1" Name="param"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue"
            ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You can do it from code behind. You just need to get the value of selectedItem of First DDL and and the select the data from database on this basis of selected value of first DDL and then just bind the second DDL with this filtered data

Comment: I didn't get you? what are you trying to ask?

Comment: i guess i did it.  but there is a problem. when i try second time   city values increasing adding new one

Comment: You need to clear the items of dropdown before adding again otherwise it will add every time on postback

Comment: you don't have to use any code behind. Did you try my answer?

Comment: at first run its working but clear is a problem now. thanks a lot for your interesting.

Comment: DropDownList1.Items.Clear(); other problem is ok!

Comment: By this you can clear items of DDL1, I think now you can go ahead with your code :)

Comment: hi again me are you there? i have a questions

Comment: if there is a one recorded city in database there is no problem. b

Comment: No, if there is one record in database then it will display if it comes under your filter criteria

Comment: but for exp. if there are 3 different city recorded to same personname, when i select the name show ddl2 all of the city names but show only first record detail in gridview. when i select other city gridview shows all the record

Comment: You can put a separate question on stackoverflow, because it's not possible to get the cause here and even here already we have put lots of comments

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use the first ddl value as a parameter in your second DDL data source. If you set autopostback to true on the first DDL the scecond one will poplulate on postback.

Comment: "All you have to do is use the first ddl value as a parameter in your second DDL data source"

how can i do this?